# Java photo manipulation library (want to achive something like Apple Photo booth stretch effect)

Tags: java, android

I want to achive something like the Apple Photo booth stretch effect on android: [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aPhoto_Booth%27s_Stretch_Effect.jpg)

Is there already a Java library which implements this kind of manipulation or do I have to write one from scrap (start manually manipulateing pixels on bitmap etc)? If I have to write it from scrap, how would the general logic would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you the jhlabs filters API:
http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html

with the Wrap effect:
http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/WarpFilter.html

I've used it for my java software http://decoration.japplis.com which is a JavaSE software. It may need small changes for Android (it's open source).